# automation testing for background service Android

Tags: android, testing, service, background, automation

I am trying for automation testing for my Android background service. Could someone suggest is there any good way to do it.

I have seen there are so many automations for UI testing, but i haven't found any automation for Background services

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there are no automation tests for Services is because usually as a developer you know exactly what to test depending on the Service and it's perhaps not easy to find out what a service method should return (not impossible but hard).

Then, Services are tested by the developers implementing it.

To create an integration test for your Service you should

- write an instrumented JUnit4 test class
- create the corresponding `ServiceTestRule` to start (and shutdown) the Service
- bind to the Service
- exercise the exposed Service methods

Take a look at [Testing your Service](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/integration-testing/service-testing.html) for greater details.

Comment: The downside of the ServiceTestRule is that you cannot test if your service shuts down correctly. There is no stopService() method, and the onDestroy() method in your service is never called. I can call it myself from the test but that is not how it works in the actual application.